# List joined teams failed with delegated permission

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

*{ "error": { "code": "AuthenticationError", "message": "Error authenticating with resource.", "innerError": { "request-id": "525e9057-9f49-4ef3-b3d1-200ec34033e6", "date": "2017-07-15T01:33:22" } } }*

When I try to list joined teams, it always failed with this error. But just a little times it will work.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_joinedteams

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Very strange! My graph resource is 'https://graph.microsoft.com/' that ends with '/'. When I remove '/', this error disappears.

Comment: Can you share the relevant code for you getting a token? Can you share a token which works and a token which does not work? My guess is that you are messing up somewhere in your code where you generate the endpoint url, and the backslash is causing the URL to be bad, rather than a specific authentication issue.

Comment: I'm hitting the same error when requesting joinedTeams, any update on this?

Comment: I get this error intermittently, as well. It randomly starts to work and then will randomly stop working, I wonder if it has to do with the Teams API still being in beta?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_list): https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_list

Under the Permissions section, you will see that when you create the Enterprise Application (assuming Azure AD), you need to specify the permissions and grant them to the application (If using Azure AD 2, they you set the scope in the code and not through the portal)

The problem I'm running into is that the User.Read.All and User.Read.Write require Admin privileges - I read that even with this, one only gets access to their own directory resources.

In short, you are not assigning the right permissions to your application which is why you get the error when executing the GET groups